# How to make dropdown and sub dropdowns list using with Array groups in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am trying to append the array groups data but i don't know how to append the sub array group data. category and sub_1 is working but in sub_list name data is not working

```js
let nav_list = [
    {
        category: "Dropdown 1",
        sub_1: "Sub 1",
        sub_list: [
            { name: "Sub 2" },
            { name: "Sub 2" },
        ]
    },
    {
        category: "Dropdown 2",
        sub_1: "Sub 1",
        sub_list: [
            { name: "Sub 2" },
            { name: "Sub 2" },
        ]
    },
];
let nav_ul = $('.navLists');
let nv_data = ``;
for(let data of  nav_list){
    nv_data += `
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
     role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">${data.category}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li class="dropright">
 
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown">${data.sub_1}</a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
   
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">${data.sub_list.name}</a>
    </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
    </li>     
    `;
}
nav_ul.append(nv_data);
```

```html
 <ul class="navLists"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `sub_list` is json array so to access it you need to use `for` loop i.e:  `for (let datas of data.sub_list)` .Also , you need to change the way `htmls` are getting appended to your variable `nv_data` so that you don't get repeated data .

***Demo Code*** :

```js
let nav_list = [{
    category: "Dropdown 1",
    sub_1: "Sub 1",
    sub_list: [{
        name: "Sub 2"
      },
      {
        name: "Sub 2"
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    category: "Dropdown 2",
    sub_1: "Sub 1",
    sub_list: [{
        name: "Sub 2"
      },
      {
        name: "Sub 2"
      },
    ]
  },
];
let nav_ul = $('.navLists');
let nv_data = ``;
for (let data of nav_list) {
  nv_data += `
    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown"
     role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">${data.category}</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
    <li class="dropright">
 
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-toggle" href="" data-toggle="dropdown">${data.sub_1}</a><div class="dropdown-menu">`
  //for accessing sublist array
  for (let datas of data.sub_list) {
    nv_data += ` <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">${datas.name}</a> `;
  }
  nv_data += `</div> </li></ul> </li>`;


}
nav_ul.append(nv_data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="navLists"></ul>
```